# Python Global Variable not setting to new value

Tags: python, time

```
global endGame
endGame = False



def time_up():
  global endGame
  endGame = True
```

This code is not setting the endGame variable to the new value. I do not see what I am doing wrong. This is not all of the code as the site wouldn't let me post it all on here. But I am setting the endGame variable to True so i can stop a while loop which is executing my game play code.
Here is the link to the full source -

http://pastebin.com/7gEkfWa1

Comment: Using `global` in global scope makes no sense, and have you called the function `time_up` in your code? (you need to call the function in order to execute its code)

Comment: Works for me. I think you must be leaving out a crucial detail of your problem.

Comment: What ever you are trying to do, this is the wrong way. Figure out how to eliminate the global variable.

Answer (score 2):

`time_up()` function must be called in order to produce some effect:

```
In [1]: endGame = False

In [2]: endGame
Out[2]: False

In [3]: def time_up():
   ...:     global endGame
   ...:     endGame = True
   ...:     

In [4]: endGame
Out[4]: False

In [5]: time_up()

In [6]: endGame
Out[6]: True
```

Comment: I am calling the time_up function and still returns as False as if the assignment of the bool value True had no effect ... totally confused right now. http://pastebin.com/7gEkfWa1

Comment: in your code you write == instead of =. You're confronting not assignig. H

Comment: @KyleKirkby Always make sure the code you post in a question actually demonstrates your problem; otherwise, you waste everyone's time.